# Trouble with Async threads and event loops in python

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm having trouble understanding this error, generated by this block of code here:

```
def websock():

    while True:

        async def WebSocketserver(websocket, path):
        
            global message
            global logmsg
        
            while True:
                Rxdata = await websocket.recv()
                # construct the message that we will log
                data = json.loads(Rxdata)
                command = data.get('Message')
                person = data.get('Name')
                commandTime = data.get('Time')
                message = command
                logmsg = [person, message, str(commandTime), "allowed", "console"]
                print(f" {person} on the controller: {command}")
                await websocket.send("200")

        start_server = websockets.serve(WebSocketserver, Host, SocketPort)

        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Which gives me the error that:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\twitch\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner       
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\twitch\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\CloudStorage\OneDrive - Personal\OneDrive\Projects-R2D2\scripts-twitchPlays\code\TwitchPlays_2\TwitchPlaysCode.py", line 276, in websock
    start_server = websockets.serve(WebSocketserver, Host, SocketPort)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\twitch\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\server.py", line 999, in __init__
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\twitch\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

What does it mean that there is no event loop? isn't the while statement supposed to cover that? Im borrowing this understanding from here: https://medium.com/@tigranbs/concurrency-vs-event-loop-vs-event-loop-concurrency-eb542ad4067b but I am very lost at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research I think I have come across a possible answer that might work:

```
def websock():

    async def WebSocketserver(websocket, path):
    
        global message
        global logmsg
    
        while True:
            Rxdata = await websocket.recv()
            # construct the message that we will log
            data = json.loads(Rxdata)
            command = data.get('Message')
            person = data.get('Name')
            commandTime = data.get('Time')
            message = command
            logmsg = [person, message, str(commandTime), "allowed", "console"]
            print(f" {person} on the controller: {command}")
            await websocket.send("200")

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    start_server = websockets.serve(WebSocketserver, Host, SocketPort)

    loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
    loop.run_forever()
```

Writing the function out like so makes sense -- why since before we call the webserver serve method there was no event loop now with an event loop it can serve the web server on that -- so creating an eventloop - setting it to the right asyncio loop and then setting it to run until complete (which is kinda forever since the loop is while true) and setting it to run forever should make it run. Atleast this code doesn't give me errors - so if anyone (arguable more famialir with this) can either confirm this thought pattern - that would be great!